# Check for same key in 2 different dictionaries, print the key and both values

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

Not sure why I can't figure this out but I want the program to look into 2 dictionaries and if the key matches I want it to print the key along with the values from both dictionaries like so..

[Result]

```
a 1 2
b 2 4
c 3 6
d 4 8
```

[CODE]

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4})
b = Counter({'a':2,'b':4,'c':6,'d':8})

for key in b.most_common():
    if set(a.keys()) == set(b.keys()):
        print(key)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) of both keys :

```
>>> set(a.keys()) & set(b.keys())
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
```

Here's an example with dicts that aren't exactly similar:

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5})
b = Counter({'a':2,'b':4,'c':6,'d':8,'f':7})

common_keys = set(a.keys()) & set(b.keys())

for key in common_keys:
    print("%s %d %d" % (key, a[key], b[key]))
# a 1 2
# c 3 6
# b 2 4
# d 4 8
```

Note that the conversion to `set` doesn't preverse the `Counter` order.

You could convert the `set` to a `list` and sort it depending on the sum of both values :

```
a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5}
b = {'a':2,'b':4,'c':6,'d':8,'f':7}

common_keys = list(set(a.keys()) & set(b.keys()))

common_keys.sort(key=lambda k: a[k] + b[k], reverse=True)

for key in common_keys:
    print("%s %d %d" % (key, a[key], b[key]))
# d 4 8
# c 3 6
# b 2 4
# a 1 2
```

Finally, if you don't care about sorting the keys according to the sum of their values, here's a slightly modified version of your code:

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4})
b = Counter({'a':2,'b':4,'c':6,'d':8})

for key, a_value in a.most_common():
    if key in b:
        print("%s %d %d" % (key, a_value, b[key]))
```

Comment: Isn't converting a set to a list then sorting it a little bit over-engineered? I think it's easier in this case to simply iterate over the keys in `most_common` then do a membership test, so you only need one pass.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Yes. I still wanted to preserve the most_common functionality. Thanks for the comment, I updated the code but then realized it's basically what you already wrote.

Comment: Well, I'm not Dutch or anything like that, but I guess there should be only one obvious way to do it ;)

Comment: What about sorting it by the the value in a {} ? it seems that it sorts it by the value of b {}

Comment: @rogernm001: You cannot sort by both `a` and `b` at the same time, you have to choose. The first example doesn't sort, the second examples sorts by `a + b` and the last one by `b`. If you want to sort by `a`, just switch `a` and `b` in the loop and `if`.

Comment: Yes, I just needed it to be sorted by the other value instead

Answer (score 0):

```
common_keys = sorted(set(a.keys()).intersection(b.keys()))

for key in common_keys:
    print(key, a[key], b[key])
```

Comment: Do make sure you explain as well

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, your `if` condition was off, and `most_common` returns a list of *tuples*, so you need to unpack the key-value pair

```
>>> a = Counter({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4})
>>> b = Counter({'a':2,'b':4,'c':6,'d':8})
>>> for key, bval in b.most_common():
...     if key in a:
...         print(key, a[key], bval)
...
d 4 8
c 3 6
b 2 4
a 1 2
>>>
```

If you don't care about the order, (i.e. you don't need to call `most_common`) you could just iterate over the intersection. In python 3, this is very easy:

```
>>> a.keys() & b.keys()
{'d', 'a', 'c', 'b'}
>>>
```

Because `.keys` actually returns a view that acts more like a set than a list.

```
>>> for common_key in a.keys() & b.keys():
...     print(common_key, a[common_key], b[common_key])
...
d 4 8
a 1 2
c 3 6
b 2 4
>>>
```

Comment: This works nicely! when I incorporate it into my code however I get an error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) :/

Comment: @rogernm001 uhhh you're seeing the output of a terminal session, so I'm not sure what exactly is causing that error. I'm guessing it's coming from the `for key, bval...` line?

Comment: Yes that line.. the actual data in my dictionaries are like so a = {('192.168.10.2' , 7), ('192.168.10.5', 11)...} AND b ={('192.168.10.2' , 65596), ('192.168.10.5, 95943...)} ... Could this be the reason?

Comment: @rogernm001 Yes.  This are not dictionaries, those are *sets* of tuples. The `Counter` object is counting the *tuples*, not the first value in the tuple. Try it with a small example.

Comment: ah I provided the wrong example my mistake, they were at first dictionaries but I changed them.